# PHP CURL File Download disk performance

Tags: php, curl, disk

I have a application based on php which downloads a large number of 5-10 MB files from a server and stores it. I currently download the files using CURL using CURLOPT_FILE option as below.

```
$ch=curl_init($url);
$fp=fopen($filename);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_exec($ch);
```

However, I have noticed that my laptop starts heating up when downloading for large amount of time.

Is it possible because of more read/write accesses. Would reading the file first to memory (as in the code below)  and then saving it to disk reduce the heating?

```
$ch=curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$st=curl_exec($ch);
file_put_contents($file,$st);
```

Comment: Your idea won't work (PHP does not have pointers). Is it possible to download the files using bash scripts?

Comment: Which idea? Both these codes will work. I just wanted to know which would be better for my disk health

Comment: Since those are small size files.why don't you give it a try ?

Comment: @ShaunakGupte The idea to read it into memory. You would need pointers and a malloc to do that (which you obviously do not have if you're using PHP).

Comment: @no92 no, you are wrong.second code block will first download the entire file to the memory and then write it to the disk.

Comment: @Himal You can't access memory from PHP. PHP is an interpreted language, which typically do memory management for you (and thus do not provide you with the methods for accessing memory). Or did you see a `malloc` in PHP? The file is saved in a variable, which isn't exactly storing it into memory. Also note that it may not the best way to do that (variables are stored in a hash table if I'm not wrong), especially when the files get bigger.

Comment: @no92 looks like you don't know what you are talking about.where do you think the variable is stored ? yes, in php we don't have to do memory management our self but it doesn't mean that php doesn't use memory.as i said earlier, the second code block will first store the file in memory(will not write to the disk untill it has the complete file). in this case it probably won't be an issue becasue these files are small in size.please read more on how php work before posting this types of comments.Thank you.